# Trigger to fetch unrelated object record

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity, account, after-trigger

How to update unrelated object feild when opportunity is created with related account which has same name email phone as in lead

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to update other records, you need to query those records according to the logic you looking for and then update them. Since they are different records, you can update them in either `before` or `after` trigger.

In this case you may be trying to update lead in other accounts so query for those leads using current record email, make change and save it.